# How do you mute background music when you change view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I'm trying to create an application that plays a sound in one view controller (background music) and mutes it in the other view controllers. I have the part of the code figured out for playing background music but I can't get the application to mute it in another window? How do you I fix this? Thank you so much! :)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Waltz" ofType:@"wav"];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error: NULL];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [audioPlayer play];`
```

Comment: Put the logic in the main view controller instead of the app delegate.

Comment: Ah..Now why didn't I think of that! Thank you sir! :)

Comment: viewDidLoad:  viewDidUnload: should be the place you want.

Comment: @KirkSpaziani `viewDidUnload` hasn't been used since iOS 5..

Comment: @rmaddy Wowie!  I gotta catch up.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use notifications to pause/restart the music.  That way, a view controller that doesn't know anything about the music player could simply:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"STOP_MUSIC" object:nil];
```

Comment: Ah...Thank you Jeffrey! You answered my question. Now why didn't I think of using a "notification" to call it? Thank you again!